# Dynamically change auto constraints width

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I have a custom cell with auto layout. I added a width constraint to a label. Is there a way to dynamically change its width? (For example when the user rotates the iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the constraint, or when it's created in the XIB file, save a reference to the constraint in a variable. Then, when you need to change the width you can change the .constant property of the constraint.

The constant property is pretty much the only property that can be changed on a constraint after it's assigned to a view.

Since the constraint is created in the Storyboard, then create an outlet from the constraint to a variable in the view controller that contains the view being constrained. Then, when appropriate, change the 'constant' property of the constraint.

Comment: Can you post the code where you're creating the constraint?

Comment: The constraint is added in the storyBoard

Comment: @MikeRally You can make an `IBOutlet` to an `NSLayoutConstraint` like any other UI element. Declare it in your code and then link to it from your Storyboard. Just like a `UILabel` or `UIButton`, etc...